# Sencha-Touch click Ext.image

Tags: events, extjs, sencha-touch

i have a problem on sencha touch.

When i click on one image, i want to  hide the other images

here my code:

```
config: {
fullscreen: true,
id: 'ViewEstimation',
styleHtmlContent: true,
items: [{
        xtype:'panel',
        layout:'vbox',
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                layout:'hbox',
                items: [
                    Image0,
                    Image1,
                    Image2,
                    Image3,
                    Image4,
                    Image5,
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                layout:'hbox',
                items: [
                    Image6,
                    Image7,
                    Image8,
                    Image9,
                    Image10,
                    Image11
                ]
            },
        ]   
}]      
}
```

My Images are declared in another file.
here  an example:

```
     var Image0 = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
                src: 'mysource',
                id: 'Image0',
                width: 108,
                height: 150
    });
```

I try to make an event on global items but i can't retrieve image id

Someone can help me ??

Comment: Did you try to get the id using Ext.getCmp('[ID OF THE IMAGE]')??

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, try with something like:

```
config: {
    ref: {
        img: '#ViewEstimation image'
    }

    control: {
        img: {
            tap: 'onImageTap'
        }
    }
},

onImageTap: function(image) {
    this.getImg.setHidden(true);
    image.setHidden(false);
}
```

Hope it helps.